# android ClassCastException on findViewById

Tags: android, layout, classcastexception

I've got a little problem where I can't find the mistake I am making, it's probably something really simple.

I've got the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStarred"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_gray"/>


    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgPriority"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:text="CheckedTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPriority"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_priority_5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I try to get a view from it with findViewById i get a ClassCast Exception

```
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at com.bilobait.taskbox.task.TaskBoxTaskList$TaskView.<init>(TaskBoxTaskList.java:459)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at com.bilobait.taskbox.task.TaskBoxTaskList$TaskBoxTaskAdapter.getView(TaskBoxTaskList.java:423)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1435)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1256)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1167)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1862)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3695)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-23 10:12:07.680: E/AndroidRuntime(5965):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can somebody help me / give me a hint what i'm missing??

Thx

EDIT: Forgot something, when I take away

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgPriority"
```

from CheckedTextView the error is gone.

```
lblTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblTitle);
            lblDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblDescription);
            cbCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            imgStar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgStarred);
            imgPriority = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPriority);
```

Comment: What id do you pass to `findViewById` method?

Comment: Are u typecasting the view properly? It should be like ImageView imgStarred = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgStarred);

Comment: Please provide your java file if possible

Comment: guessing build problem, use Project->Clean.

Comment: Pls. provide java file or provide the line where you get the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't notice by the time of my first answer that you create ids in your references many times. You shouldn't do that :). Remove all `"+"` signs in all references like `layout_toLeftOf`, `layout_alignRight`, `layout_below` and so on. This will look that way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStarred"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/checkBox"
        android:layout_below="@id/checkBox"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_gray"/>


    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/checkBox"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgPriority"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox"
        android:text="CheckedTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/lblTitle"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPriority"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_priority_5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When you write, for example, `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgPriority"` with plus sign **you do** create another imgPriority id, and **you do not** referene already present id of your ImageView.

Comment: thannks a lot...works perfectly now. btw: i used the eclipse layout editor for creating the layout, and it created the wrong ids...maybe a bug?

Comment: I also stumbled onto this problem and noticed that cleaning and rebuilding was required after removing the extra plus signs. The extra ids were not removed from the R.id file until rebuilding.

Comment: Interesting that this doesn't cause a crash every time or on every device. I just discovered the same issue several months after shipping  a version with the stray + signs.

Answer (score 3):

Remove "`+`" sign from attribute `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgPriority"` in `CheckedTextView` annotation and put `ImageView` annotation in your layout xml before its id is used

Comment: what @a.ch. means is that while using RelativeLayout, you need to use the object's id as a reference only hence android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgPriority" 
The "+" basically means you're assigning an id not referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

define

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPriority"
       ........... />
```

before

```
CheckedTextView .
```

in relativeLayout every view related to other should be define after that view

Comment: did it. now im getting the exeptiong when i try to find the lblTitle

Comment: dear n0n4m3 . try and understand what does it mean . define one then define and relate two with1 now define three and relate with 1 or 2 . go in this way

Comment: thats what i did..isn't it possible to relate with 1 **and** 2 or can i only relate to one...

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Class file, you must have createed object/Find id  of different controls.
For example, im my case, when in XML file I had taken image view and I was finding id of image button in Class file, at that time this error had occured.